Encountering Illegal Instruction Error When Using QEMU to Simulate ARMv9 SME Program
I am trying to use QEMU in user mode to simulate an ARMv9 SME program, but I encounter the following error during execution:
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
Environment Information:

QEMU Version: qemu-9.0.2

Target Architecture: ARMv9


SME Code Snippet:
matmul_opt: // x0: M, x1: K, x2: N, x3: matLeft, x4: matRight, x5: matResult
  stp     x19, x20, [sp, #-48]!
  stp     x21, x22, [sp, #16]
  stp     x23, x24, [sp, #32]
  smstart
  // constants
  cntw    x6                      // SVLs
  mul     x22, x6, x1             // SVLs*K
  mul     x23, x6, x2             // SVLs*N
  add     x18, x23, x2            // SVLs*N + N
  add     x11, x4, x2, lsl #2     // Exit condition for N loop
  mov     x12, #0
  cntb    x6                      // SVLb
  mov     x14, #0
  ptrue   pn10.b                  // Predicate for SME2 VLx2 (a_ptr loads)
  whilelt pn8.s, x12, x0, vlx2    // tiles predicate (M dimension)
  sub     w6, w6, #8              // SVLb-8

.Loop_M:
  // Extract tile 0/1 and tile 2/3 predicates (M) from vlx2 predicate.
  pext    { p2.s, p3.s }, pn8[0]
  mov     x16, x4                 // b_base
  mov     x9, x5                  // c_base
  whilelt pn9.b, x16, x11, vlx2   // tiles predicate (N dimension)

.Loop_N:
  mov     x7, x3                  // a_ptr = a_base
  mov     x17, x16                // b_ptr = b_base
  mov     x10, x9                 // c_ptr0 = c_base

  // Extract tile 0/2 and tile 1/3 predicates (N) from vlx2 predicate.
  pext    { p0.b, p1.b }, pn9[0]

  add     x8, x3, x22, lsl #2     // a_base + SVLs*K FP32 elms (bytes)
  addvl   x15, x8, #-1            // Exit condition for K loop
  ld1w    {z1.s}, p2/z, [x7]      // Load 1st vector from a_ptr

  zero    {za}
  ld1w    {z2.s-z3.s}, pn9/z, [x17]  // Load 2 vectors from b_ptr

  fmopa   za0.s, p2/m, p0/m, z1.s, z2.s // ZA0+=1st a_ptr vec OP 1st b_ptr vec
  ld1w    {z5.s}, p3/z, [x7, x22, lsl #2]  // Load 2nd vector from a_ptr
  addvl   x7, x7, #1                       // a_ptr += SVLb (bytes)

.Loop_K:
  fmopa   za2.s, p3/m, p0/m, z5.s, z2.s // ZA2+=2nd a_ptr vec OP 1st b_ptr vec

  // ... (rest of the loop body)

  cmp     x7, x15
  b.mi    .Loop_K

  // ... (rest of the N loop body)

.Loop_store_ZA:
  // ... (rest of the store loop body)

  cmp     w13, w6
  b.mi    .Loop_store_ZA

  // ... (rest of the M loop body)

  smstop

  ldp     x23, x24, [sp, #32]
  ldp     x21, x22, [sp, #16]
  ldp     x19, x20, [sp], #48

  ret 

Compile Command:
aarch64-none-elf-as -march=armv9.2-a -mcpu=cortex-a710+sme2 -o test_sme test_sme.S
Run Command:
qemu-aarch64 test_sme
While executing the above program, I receive the "Illegal instruction" error. What could be the reason for this? Does my version of QEMU support the SME2 instruction set that I'm using? How can I resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Per https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/arm/cpu-features.html: are you enabling the SME feature with -M virt -cpu max?

Thank you for your suggestion! I'm not very familiar with using QEMU. The command I used is qemu-aarch64, but when I ran qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu max,sme=off  as you mentioned on the webpage, I got a black software interface with QEMU and I'm not sure how to proceed.
I am trying to compile ARM programs with SME extensions and hope to run them on my X86 Ubuntu. Can you please guide me on how to continue in this interface? Or is there another way to achieve my goal?
Thank you again for your help!

You probably want qemu-aarch64 -M virt -cpu max test_sme?

To clarify this confusion: qemu-aarch64 is for running a single binary; it doesn't take a -M option to specify a machine type, and it defaults to '-cpu max'. qemu-system-aarch64 is for running an entire guest OS system, and it does need a -M option, and does not default to '-cpu max'. The problem here is not with the command line being used.

The instruction "ptrue pn10.b" is in the FEAT_SVE2p1 extension, which QEMU does not yet implement; similarly the form of the "while" insn you are using is FEAT_SVE2p1. So you get an "illegal instruction" error, the same as you would if you ran this binary on a real CPU that didn't implement FEAT_SVE2p1. If you want to run your code under QEMU you should stick to FEAT_SME/FEAT_SVE/FEAT_SVE2 for the moment. (FEAT_SVE2p1 and FEAT_SME2 are on the todo list but may be a while yet.)
The currently emulated set of architectural features are listed here:
https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/emulation.html
